# Cocos2d: Should I use only (id)init for initializing, or can I use (void)onEnter for late allocation?

Tags: ios, architecture, cocos2d-iphone, initialization, allocation

As learning Cocos2d, I've found `- (void)onEnter`, `- (void)onExit`, can be used like their counterparts, `- (void)viewDidLoad`, `- (void)viewDidUnload` of iOS UIKit.

I do aware they are not technically good replacement for the original `- (id)init`, and I often see instructive texts for learning Cocos2d only use `- (id)init` method for all it's properties and variables.

However, if I use `- (void)onEnter` for allocation and initialization, I can reference `self.parent` for a little more cleaner code.

**Is it safe to assume I can keep using - (void)onEnter for allocating and initializing without worrying if it's right way to develop using Cocos2d framework?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are careful about your initializations and memory management, this sounds like a perfectly reasonable way to handle your code but as you mention, it's not standard so please beware of some pitfalls.

The `-(void) onEnter` and `-(void) onExit` methods are actually more like `-(void) viewWillAppear` and `-(void) viewWillDisappear` than `-(void) viewDidLoad` and `-(void) viewDidUnload`

Be aware of:

- onEnter is also called recursively on all of your node's children.
- onEnter may be called several times depending on how you handle your scenes whereas init would only be called
  once. Be careful your objects don't leak by accidentally allocating
  them more than once.

Comment: Thank you for helping my learning Cocos2d framework. Though you didn't give me negative input, I've decided not to use onEnter for initialization. Restructured my code to follow more conventional ways of using (void)init, like many instructions.

Answer (score 1):

It's doable, but a bad approach. onEnter is called when the CCNode is added to another CCNode, not when it or its parent is added to the screen. onEnter and onEnterTransitionIsFinished is meant to represent that the CCNode is loaded and ready to go. And unless you specifically keep your CCNodes outside of another CCNode (bad form), onEnter will be called immediately in the after your init. So your supposed lazy allocation is moot.

More importantly, you should be loading as much cacheable data (textures and such) at the start of your CCScene anyway, to prevent in-scene hiccups such as lazy allocation of large, and therefore, cacheable data. And if you've correctly done all that heavy lifting at the start of your scene, waiting to set some flags and number variables isn't going to do you any good. And doing so in a method that's meant for other things is even less helpful.